# Call stored proc from after insert trigger

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

Perhaps a stupid question!

If I call a stored proc from an After Insert trigger (T-SQL) - then how do I get the values of the "just inserted" data?
e.g.

```
   CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MyTrigger
    ON  dbo.MyTable 
     AFTER INSERT
    AS 
     BEGIN

       EXEC createAuditSproc 'I NEED VALUES HERE!'
```

I don't have any identity columns to worry about - I just want to use some of the "just inserted" values to pass into my sproc.

Edit: For clarification - I need this to call a sproc and not do a direct insert to the table, since the sproc does more than one thing.  I'm working with some legacy tables I can't currently amend to do things 'properly' (time/resource/legacy code), so I have to work with what I have :(

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You get to the newly 'changed' data by using the [INSERTED and DELETED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) pseudo-tables:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MyTrigger     
    ON  dbo.MyTable       
    AFTER INSERT     
AS       
    BEGIN         
        INSERT INTO myTableAudit(ID, Name)
        SELECT i.ID, i.Name
           FROM inserted i;
    END
```

Given the example tables

```
create table myTable
(
    ID INT identity(1,1),
    Name varchar(10)
)
GO

create table myTableAudit
(
    ID INT,
    Name varchar(10),
    TimeChanged datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
GO
```

**Edit** : Apologies, I didn't address the bit about calling a Stored Proc. As per marc_s's comment, note that inserted / deleted can contain multiple rows, which complicates matters with a SPROC. Personally, I would leave the trigger inserting directly into the audit table without the encapsulation of a SPROC. However, if you have SQL 2008, you can use table valued parameters, like so:

```
CREATE TYPE MyTableType AS TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    Name varchar(10)
);
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.MyAuditProc @MyTableTypeTVP MyTableType READONLY
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        INSERT INTO myTableAudit(ID, Name)
        SELECT mtt.ID, mtt.Name
            FROM @MyTableTypeTVP mtt;
    END
GO
```

And then your trigger would be altered as like so:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.MyTrigger
    ON  dbo.MyTable       
    AFTER INSERT     
AS       
    BEGIN         
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @MyTableTypeTVP AS MyTableType;

        INSERT INTO @MyTableTypeTVP(ID, Name)
        SELECT i.ID, i.Name
            FROM inserted i;

        EXEC dbo.MyAuditProc @MyTableTypeTVP;
    END
```

you can then test that this works for both a single and multiple inserts

```
insert into dbo.MyTable values ('single');

insert into dbo.MyTable 
    select 'double'
union
    select 'insert';
```

However, if you are using SQL 2005 or lower, you would probably need to use a cursor to loop through inserted passing rows to your SPROC, something too horrible to contemplate.

As a side note, if you have SQL 2008, you might look at [Change Data Capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540056/for-auditing-triggers-or-cdc)

**Edit #2** : Since you need to call the proc, and if you are certain that you only insert one row ...

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.MyTrigger
    ON  dbo.MyTable       
    AFTER INSERT     
AS       
    BEGIN         
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @SomeInt INT;
        DECLARE @SomeName VARCHAR(10);

        SELECT TOP 1 @SomeInt = i.ID, @SomeName = i.Name
        FROM INSERTED i;

        EXEC dbo.MyAuditProc @SomeInt, @SomeName;
    END;
```

Comment: +1 and also remember that those `Inserted` and `Deleted` tables will potentially contain several rows - not just a single one! Never assume that just a single row is being processed in a trigger!

Comment: How do I get those values as stored proc parameters? Do I need to declare them all and then 'select @param1 = val1, @param2 = val2' and then pass those in?

Comment: @param1 = val1 is one way, but since you could be working with multiple rows, I recommend either implementing the table argument or using a cursor to call the stored proc once for each row of data inserted.