# SQL Trigger to Call a Stored Procedure with inserted value as parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-insert

I would like to monitor a table for inserts and call a stored procedure with the value which has been inserted.

Monitored Table (BatchDetails) will have the following columns
BatchID,BatchStartTime,BatchEndTime

Stored Procedure will use the latest BatchID which has been inserted

Note:
There will always be only one row inserted at a time.

I have been looking at this link but seem that there is lot going on i.e., several tables. Is there a simple way of doing this?

[Call stored proc from after insert trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887877/call-stored-proc-from-after-insert-trigger#)

Comment: inserts can affect *mutliple* rows, and triggers fire once per statement, not once per row. Usually, you should put the (small amount) of logic *in* the trigger, rather than calling out to a stored proc. What does the stored proc *do*?

Comment: There will be only one row inserted at a time. There will never be more than one row inserted.

Comment: It seems to me that the question you linked to yourself has all the info that is needed to answer your question, if only you just take the time to study it.

Comment: *"Note: There will always be only one row inserted at a time."* It's this kind of thinking that will make the future you hate the present you in 3, 6, or 12 months from now, when someone will decide to change it and insert a bunch of rows in a single statement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Monitor_BatchDetails_Inserts 
    ON BatchDetails
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @BatchId INT
    SELECT TOP 1 @BatchId = BatchId
    FROM    INSERTED
    ORDER BY [PK_ColumnHere/Date/OtherOrderingColumn] DESC

    EXEC    SomeStoredProc @BatchId
END
```

But there are a few flaws with it:

1 - **there CAN be more rows in `INSERTED`** (rows that are being inserted) and this wont handle all of them

2 - you may want to call your procedure from where the inserts are being made into `BatchDetails` table. Maybe have a proc that does the inserts, and add there the call to this your procedure. That will be a better way to approach this.

Hope it makes sense

Comment: If you're going to write a trigger that can only handle single-row inserts, I'd normally insist that it includes a *check* for that precondition and throws an error if it's not met. Otherwise its a bug waiting to bite someone in (6 months, a year, etc) later when they start performing multi-row inserts.

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating a bit on previous answer and considering more than 1 inserted row you could try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Monitor_BatchDetails_Inserts 
    ON BatchDetails
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @BatchId INT
    Declare bcursor cursor local for
    SELECT BatchId FROM INSERTED ORDER BY [PK_ColumnHere/Date/OtherOrderingColumn] DESC
    open bcursor
    fetch next from bcursor into @BatchId
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin
        EXEC    SomeStoredProc @BatchId
        fetch next from bcursor into @BatchId
    end
    close bcursor
    deallocate bcursor
END
```

Comment: For next time, there's a complete [Markdown formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) available.